# Add labels to columns in highcharts pie chart legend

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I am working on highcharts and I have problem with legend. I have 4 columns in legend of pie chart and need to give headings to each of these columns. I am using following code and result is given below.

[image: pie chart - 4 columns legend]

```
               useHTML: true,
                labelFormatter: function () {

                    return '<div style="width:800px"><span style="float:left;width:200px">' + this.name + '</span><span>'
                        + this.description + '</span><span style="float:right;width:100px">' + this.target + '</span><span style="float:right;width:100px">' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 0) + '%</span></div>';
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable a legend formatter and then prepare your own HTML legend, creating a style which you need. Example of simple HTML legend:

```
$legend = $('#customLegend');

    $.each(chart.series[0].data, function (j, data) {

        $legend.append('<div class="item"><div class="symbol" style="background-color:'+data.color+'"></div><div class="serieName" id="">' + data.name + '</div></div>');

    });

    $('#customLegend .item').click(function(){
        var inx = $(this).index(),
            point = chart.series[0].data[inx];

        if(point.visible)
            point.setVisible(false);
        else
            point.setVisible(true);
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/N3KAC/1/

Comment: Thanks a lot. You made my day :)

Comment: Nowhere found this solution, you are genius.